# Is it possible to have multiple versions of the same ESRI Addin on the same machine?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, add-in

I will be adding new functionality to a ESRI addin that I have created and I would like to give it to users to test.

They already have a working version.

Is it possible to install 2 versions of the same addin, one that is the current version (v2.1) and another that they can beta test(v3.0)?

If it is possible, how do I get this to work?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Comment: I think you would need to give it a different AddInID guid in Config.esriaddinx. Also might need to name it differently so you can tell which one is active in the ArcGIS UI.